# Control a c program from the web on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, jquery, c, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a C program on a Raspberry Pi that waits (in a loop) for an external user input to start or stop the acquisition of data, and I would like to control it in some way from a webserver hosted on the raspberry.
 
At the moment, to start or stop the acquisition, I am using jquery to write on a txt file that is read in a polling way from the C program.
Are there any other (less ugly) solution to control the program from the webserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use nodejs and then you'll be able to access FS module and other useful node modules to communicate with your C program , take a look :

- [here](http://weworkweplay.com/play/raspberry-pi-nodejs/)
- [How to Turn Your Raspberry Pi Into a Development Server](http://www.toptal.com/raspberry-pi/how-to-turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-development-server)
- [Raspberry Pi and Node.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6g53Hm0rq4)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can simple use CGI or Fast CGI.

I think this is a good resource to start with: http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fastcgi-prog-guide/ch2c.htm

Edit: with this technology you get a better code structure and you use the given resources more efficiently than with a polling loop.